# Optional Parameters as Condition in a Cursor (PL/SQL)

Tags: parameters, plsql, cursor

I have a function/procedure that takes optional parameters. If provided, I need to use the parameters as conditions for cursors. If not provided, then I don't want that condition.

Here is a very simplified version of what I've come up with:

```
create or replace procedure check_data
  (p_parm1 in varchar2 default null,
   p_parm2 in number default null)
is
begin
  if (p_parm1 is null && p_parm2 is null) then
    for rec in (select col_1, col_2
        from table_a)
    loop
      /*Statements, use rec.col_1 and rec.col_2 */
    end loop;
  elsif (p_parm1 is null) then
    for rec in (select col_1, col_2
                from table_a
                where /*condition using p_parm2 */)
    loop
      /*Statements, use rec.col_1 and rec.col_2 */
    end loop;
  elsif (p_parm2 is null) then
    for rec in (select col_1, col_2
                from table_a
                where /*condition using p_parm1 */)
    loop
      /*Statements, use rec.col_1 and rec.col_2 */
    end loop;
  else
    for rec in (select col_1, col_2
                from table_a
                where /*condition using p_parm1 */
                  and /*condition using p_parm2 */)
  loop
      /*Statements, use rec.col_1 and rec.col_2 */
    end loop;
  end if;
end;
```

Is there a way to have the Cursor once and indicate which conditions to ignore if parameters aren't provided?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the query take care of all scenarios in one go, e.g.:

```
select col_1, col_2
from table_a
where (p_parm1 IS NULL OR (p_parm1 = ...))
AND   (p_parm2 IS NULL OR (p_parm2 = ...));
```

Comment: I'll try this. I've had a COALESCE function suggested and set the variables to wildcards when not provided, ei:

v_variable1 := COALESCE(p_parm1, '%');

/* then in the where clause */
where expression LIKE v_variable1;

but this causes a massive table scan that takes far too long to return. My fear is that a single query to take all scenarios will have similar performance, but I will try it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Also possible is to use nvl, it's a bit shorter:

```
select col1, col2
from table_a
where col1 = nvl(p_parm1,col1)
and col2 = nvl(p_parm2,col2);
```

So what you do: when p_parm1 is null, you equal it to the column of the condition (in the case you compare col1 to p_parm1).

Comment: I apparently need 15 reputation to vote up, but this method does work. I think my efficiency takes a massive hit as I'm selecting against a view, but perhaps I can work around that. The concept works and get's me started on a solution. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure check_data
  (p_parm1 in varchar2 default null,
   p_parm2 in number default null)
is
begin
    select col1, col2
    from table_a
    where (CASE
      WHEN (p_parm1 IS NOT NULL AND col1 = p_parm1) THEN (1)
      WHEN (p_parm1 IS NULL) THEN (1)
      ELSE 0
    END) = 1
```

Same for *p_parm2* if needed.